# JavaScript object returning null value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is wrong with this code?

```js
function makeGamePlayer(int) {
    var bal = 0;
    var obj = {
        fun1: function () {
            bal += int;
        },
        fun2: function () {
            return bal;
        }
    };
    return obj;
}
console.log(makeGamePlayer(100)); //obj
console.log(makeGamePlayer(100).fun2());   //returning 0 but expecting the 100
```

I tried running the above code but I'm not getting the correct results. I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never called `fun1`.

Comment: But bal is a global variable it should return 100 right

Comment: no, it's **not global** and  **you never add anything to it anywhere because you never call fun1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ONLY way to make the second console.log output 100 **without** changing the `makeGamePlayer` code at all is as follows

```js
function makeGamePlayer(int) {
    var bal = 0;
    var obj = {
        fun1: function () {
            bal += int;
        },
        fun2: function () {
            return bal;
        }
    };
    return obj;
}

// commented, as it's irrelevant
//console.log(makeGamePlayer(100)); //obj

var x = makeGamePlayer(100); // x is a **different obj and bal by the way**
x.fun1();
console.log(x.fun2()); 

// to illustrate that each time you call `makeGamePlayer` you get a new obj and a new bal

var y = makeGamePlayer(1000);
y.fun1();
// note, this is STILL 100
console.log(x.fun2()); 
// this outputs 1000
console.log(y.fun2()); 
// output
// 100
// 100
// 1000
```

Answer (score -2):

You are incrementing int in fun1 function, but you haven't called in anywhere.  You have called fun2 function which is returning the bal as it is.